# MultiValueDictKeyError when getting a Post Value in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an online store in Django.  In the views file, I'm looping through the list to see if the product id matches what the user submitted.  However, I keep getting "MultiValueDictKeyError".  Is there a way I can fix this?

VIEWS FILE

```
def index(request):
products = {
    "items" : items
}
return render(request, "app_main/index.html", products)

def buy(request):

for item in items:
     if item['id'] == int(request.POST['i_id']): ##<<--THIS IS WHERE IT 
                                                              ERRORS
     amount_charged = item['price'] * int(request.POST['quantity'])

try:
    request.session['total_charged']
except KeyError:
    request.session['total_charged'] = 0

try:
    request.session['total_items']
except KeyError:
    request.session['total_items'] = 0        

request.session['total_charged'] += amount_charged
request.session['total_items'] += int(request.POST['quantity'])
request.session['last_transaction'] = amount_charged
```

HTML FILE

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {% for i in items %}
    <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.price }}</td>
    <td>
        <form action='/buy' method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name='quantity'>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        </select>
        <input type='hidden' name='{{ i.id }}'/>
        <input type='submit' value='Buy!' />
        </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because `i_id` doesn't declare in the template, you should change;

```
<input type='hidden' name='{{ i.id }}'/>
```

to;

```
<input type='hidden' name="i_id" value='{{ i.id }}'/>
```